# Memory consumption by printf( )

Tags: c++, c

Does displaying a simple statement in C (or C++) occupy some memory?
For example,

```
//in C
printf("\nHello World");
//in C++
cout<<"Hello World" ;
```

and, will it make a difference if I attach some value of a variable to be displayed in the same statement?
For example,

```
printf("Value is %d" , var) ;
```

Comment: yes. the string has to be stored SOMEWHERE for the rest of the code to operate on it. And yes, the more your code "does", the more there has to be of it. if you don't stuff a variable into the output, then the entire block of "put variable into output" code doesn't have to get included

Comment: @MarcB so how much memory does it occupies?

Comment: Also, consider the size of the library that printf is defined in.  You must load the entire library in order to use it.

Comment: How much memory does what occupy? Your question is pretty vague. Are you talking about memory for the data you're passing? Possible stack memory consumption for the call itself? Local variables used inside printf? Something else?

Comment: It can be quite serious issue in some embedded cases, a single %f can cause a whole floating-point library to get linked in:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does displaying a simple statement in C(or C++) occupies some memory?

Yes, of course.  The string constant has to be stored somewhere, usually in a read-only segment of memory.  The `printf` and `cout` facilities also take up space.

> will it make a difference if i attach some value of a variable to be displayed in the same statement?

Yes.  The parameters have to be stored somewhere, usually on the stack, so the memory used by the parameters will be returned after the `printf` or `cout` call ends.  Also the call itself probably generates a few more instructions in the calling routine to push the parameters on the stack.

Comment: does these two occupy same amount of memory?
printf("hello");   and  printf("hello world") ;

Comment: Read-only data memory, no -- `"hello world"` takes up 12 bytes instead of `"hello"`'s 6 bytes.  The rest would take up probably the same amount of memory (call stack, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Code occupies memory. String literals occupy memory. Function calls (usually) use some stack.

Generally speaking I don't think `printf` should need to perform any dynamic memory allocations in order to work. But although (I believe) it's possible to avoid it I don't think they're forbidden from doing so. The same goes for `cout <<` when outputting the types that have built-in support. If it ends up calling a user-defined overload then that can use whatever memory it likes.

Posix lists `ENOMEM` as a possible error for `printf` but not for `snprintf`. This suggests that on Posix systems (which of course is not all C implementations) the output might dynamically allocate memory, but the formatting will not.

Comment: i wouldnt say thats 'undefined'. it will simply output the value of the pointer, (the address of var).

Comment: @Octopus - as per the C standard (section 7.21.6.1~ish) if you use an incorrect format specificer for the type passed in, it's UB. It should have been `%p` in this case.

Comment: @Octopus: whether you can guess what will happen is a different issue from whether the standard defines what will happen. For most purposes, "your code has undefined behavior" is just the formal way of saying, "your code is wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. The characters in the string requires memory, so these objects are placed in the global memory, but not in the process heap. When the function is called, its arguments passes trough stack, and then the call happens.

```
push        offset string "hello, world"
call        dword ptr printf
```

We have its address, calculated by the `offset` directive. So it use sizeof(uintptr_t) bytes of stack memory.

**[UPD.]**
This code:

```
int val = 5;
printf("val = %d", val);
```

Disassembles to:

```
mov         eax, dword ptr[val]  
push        eax  
push        offset string "val = %d"
call        dword ptr printf
```

So it use `2 * sizeof(uintptr_t)` bytes of stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that printf and cout are buffered write. Chances are if the buffer is not yet filled for output and your program quits which triggers a closure of output stream port, the print string will never show.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean heap memory, then the answer is, yes (at least, in general).

We produced some middleware to run on a variety of game consoles, with GCC, visual studio and Metrowerks compilers. A common constraint in the gaming industry is that you may need to allocate to custom heaps -- so we had to ensure that our middleware library made no heap allocations (other than to a heap allocator explicitly provided to us). So ensure this, we had to:

- drop calls to print, vsprintf, ...
- drop the use of C++ streams

both of these sets of calls (in general) use the heap. printf (in general) requires the heap because of the use of format strings.

Comment: I heard some older platforms (or is it Operating Systems) don't support heap allocations. How are these functions handled there?

Comment: It’s not that heap allocation isn’t available, it’s that each time you allocate on the heap, you run the risk of running out of finite memory. Games consoles and embedded systems often preallocate all their working memory in large chunks on the stack (or the heap) to guarantee they won’t run out. Dynamic objects are often managed within pool in this space.